# Unable to launch browser from shell - it opens VSCode instead

Tags: firefox, browser, zsh

I have a problem when some shell command is trying to launch my browser. Example below with `browse` command, but same with `jupyter notebook`. It looks like the target is opened in VSCode instead.

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04, with zsh, in a pyenv virtual environment.

Thanks!

```bsh
~ browse askubuntu.com
    command= "code" args= ("code", "http://askubuntu.com")                                                                                                                                
~ Copying QUrl("http://askubuntu.com/")  to QUrl("file:///home/username/.cache/kioexec/krun/8292_0/unnamed")
    Telling kioexecd to watch path "/home/username/.cache/kioexec/krun/8292_0/unnamed" dest "http://askubuntu.com/"
    All files downloaded, will call slotRunApp shortly
    EXEC "/snap/bin/code /home/username/.cache/kioexec/krun/8292_0/unnamed"
    EXEC done
```

... then VSCode opens the target as a `html` file.

- EDIT: Same error when I run `xdg-open 'http://askubuntu.com'`
- EDIT: `xdg-settings get default-web-browser` yields `code-2.desktop`
- EDIT: if I do `xdg-settings set default-web-browser firefox.desktop`, no error raised but it doesn't actually change the value (stays as `code-2.desktop`)
- EDIT: `$BROWSER askubuntu.com` works perfectly fine
- SOLVED: Thanks to @Koen I went to System settings/Applications/Default Applications (I'm on KDE) --> Web Browser --> Open http and https URLs "in the following application: Firefox" instead of "in an application based on the contents of the URL"

Comment: I meant Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Comment: do a "echo ?" after setting the default web browser - correct value is probably firefox_firefox.desktop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xdg-settings fails silently - an echo $? can show you that return code is not 0 when it failed

return codes:

> 1 Error in command line syntax.
> 2 One of the files passed on the command line did not exist.
> 3 A required tool could not be found.
> 4 The action failed.

browse is a link to xdg-open - so you need to supply an url to open the default browser

the default browser can also be set via gui tools

- gnome: gnome-control-center - default applications - web
- KDE: System settings/Applications/Default Applications --> Web Browser --> Open http and https URLs "in the following application: Firefox"

Comment: Thank you, but `echo $?` yields code `4` when I try setting with `firefox_firefox.desktop` as well

Comment: in my system the desktop files are stored here : /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/ - check if you have a desktop file there for firefox

Comment: otherwise start gnome-control-center and select the default browser via "default applications" menu

Comment: It's /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
...while the one actually called is ~/.local/share/applications/code-2.desktop

Comment: Great! It works:

I went to System settings/Applications/Default Applications (I'm on KDE) --> Web Browser --> Open http and https URLs "in the following application: Firefox" instead of "in an application based on the contents of the URL"

Comment: Jupyter notebook also launches in the browser now. Thank you!

Comment: I'm a bit new to this stack: should I edit your answer to match the actual solution?
Anyway I edited the main question text

Comment: I updated my answer with the different points

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the http:// which defines that what you are browsing is a website instead of a file. when you type "browse" alone you get

> `xdg-open - opens a file or URL in the user's preferred application`

Try `browse http:/google.com`

This should fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it does not fix the issue.
The issue is really that it does not launch my browser.
Same when I use jupyter.
It opens VSCode instead